# React Text Input moves cursor to the end when invalid regex input is blocked in onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

In the following React code, invalid input (digits) is blocked with a regex, but in both cases, when you type a digit, the cursor moves to the end to the field, even if you weren't at the end when the blockage occurred. If you're in the middle of a string and type in a digit the cursor will take you to the end.

[image]

Option 1:

```
const handleLastNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setLastName(e.target.value.replace(/[0-9]+/g, ""));
}
```

Option 2:

```
    const handleLastNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if (!/^[A-Za-z]+$/i.test(e.target.value)) { 
            return;
        } 
        setLastName(e.target.value);
   }
```

The component is built on top of a regular input, as in most libraries,

```
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Text ..."
                        id="legalRepresentativeLastName"
                        name="legalRepresentativeLastName"
                        type="text"
                        value={legalRepresentativeLastName}
                        onBlur={handleLegalRepresentativeLastNameBlur}
                        onChange={handleLegalRepresentativeLastNameChange}
```

I need to filter out invalid chars (in this case, digits). The approach that does work is `onKeyDown` -- that one does keep the cursor stable wherever you were. But that forces me to define a very large set of allowable keys that can be pressed, such as Backspace, Delete, ArrowUp/Down/Left/Right, Home/End, etc.